# False DMCA complaint filed by competitor

Tags: google, dmca

How do I find out which of my competitors filed a DMCA complaint using my company's name as the one filing the complaint? We own trademark & copyright to this product and I have been working with Google for two months to get the issue resolved.  It's the second time this has happened and I am at my wits end.

Comment: Who was the DMCA complaint filed _against_? Yourself? From "yourself" to yourself?!

Comment: Yes, exactly. When you look at the complaint on Lumen, it says the complaint was filed against my company by my company.